# Web API Returns empty result in body

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I have A web API function that returns Facebook Id for the current user, I get the Id from session. The API function displays the id correctly but when I connect to it through a JQuery function it reruns empty string and when I try the Web API function in my browser I can see the result correctly but when I open the source page I can see only empty string Like this:
[image]

[image]

This is my function code:

```
public class successController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/success")]
    public string success()
    {
        string val = "";
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] != null)
        {
            val = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["user"].ToString();
            return val;
        }
        else
            return "";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure jquery call use get method or post?.

you can install a web sniffer like fiddler to check what differences between each call.

Comment: the JQuery is using the get method, but the problem with the Web API function not the the Jquery. I get the above results from the browser

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. I need to see more code. Or, could you try fiddler to catch request differences?

Comment: Thank you but this is my function, no more code. I make one request and the page result gives me fb id like "22366635" and when I right click on the page to view the source it is empty, nothing there. I don't know how this happens

Answer (score 0):

For the same code and logic it is working for me. Instead of cheking user session, I am returning a hard-coded string.

```
        public class SuccessController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/success")]
    public string success() {
        return "2321312312312";
    }
}
```

}

Below is my Jquery Code

```
 <script>
    $(function () {
        $.get("http://localhost:2000/api/success", function (response) {
            console.log(response); // server response
        });
    });

</script>
```

[image: Screenshot]